# Auto email using Infopath based on Sharepoint List criteria

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have a custom list in Sharepoint (no access to SharePoint Designer). When new data is uploaded into SharePoint, I will like for an auto email to be sent out to my team using Infopath. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InfoPath is a form editor, not a workflow tool. It is possible to send emails from Infopath, but what you describe requires a trigger action that is not part of InfoPath.

Maybe you can use the built-in SharePoint alerts to get notified of new data in the list.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can say your team to subscribe to list changes through out-of-box SharePoint feature "Alert Me". Like [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918). And they will get all changes in list.
2. You can add javascript to your form pages that will send emails to your team on form save. Through Utility.SendEmail method.
3. You can create periodically running code and schedule it on one of your servers. Like Console App, Windows Service, PowerShell script. It will get data from your list periodically and send email to your team.
4. May be some other ways someone can add later to this question.

Comment: This was tagged with SharePoint online, so script on servers and the rest of your item 3. is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, but I'll add that the common methods are:

1. alerts - the easiest way
2. workflow - For when alerts don't work, but is still quite a bit easier than code. Since you said you're in sharepoint online, then this sort of email can easily be sent out using Flow. [Here](https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/2bd714484de84d1391cb288208b9f609/send-a-customized-email-when-a-new-sharepoint-list-item-is-added/) is a link to a flow template that will send out a customized email when a new item is added to a SharePoint list.
3. code - there are a couple different code-based options, but only go there if one of the previous two don't work for you.